# Convex function strictly increasing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to prove that if function $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is not constant, increasing and convex then from some $c\in (a,b)$ function $f:[c,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma.** For $\forall \,u \lt v \lt w \in (a,b)\,$:

$$
\frac{f(v)-f(u)}{v-u} \le \cfrac{f(w)-f(v)}{w-v} 
$$

This simply formalizes the intuition that adjacent chords on the graph of a convex function have non-decreasing slopes, and follows directly from the definition of convexity with $\lambda = \frac{w-v}{w-u} \in [0,1]$ and $1-\lambda=\frac{v-u}{w-u}\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
& f\big(\lambda u + (1-\lambda)w)\big) \le \lambda f(u) + (1-\lambda)f(w) \\
\iff \quad & f\left(\frac{(\cancel{w}-v)u+(v-\cancel{u})w}{w-u}\right) \le \frac{w-v}{w-u} f(u) + \frac{v-u}{w-u} f(w) \\
\iff \quad & f(v) \big((w-v)+(v-u)\big) \le (w-v)f(u) + (v-u)f(w) \\
\iff \quad & \big(f(v)-f(u)\big)(w-v) \le \big(f(w)-f(v)\big)(v-u)
\end{align}
$$

**Proof.** Since $f$ is increasing and not constant there exists $\exists \,c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) \gt f(a)$. For $\forall \,x_1,x_2$ such that $a\lt c\lt x_1\lt x_2\lt b$ applying the previous **lemma** twice gives:

$$
\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} \ge \frac{f(x_1)-f(c)}{x_1-c} \ge \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a} \gt 0 
$$

The above proves that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[c,b)$ since $x_1 \gt c \implies f(x_1) \gt f(c)$ and $x_2 \gt x_1 \gt c \implies f(x_2) \gt f(x_1)$.

Comment: You are assuming that $f$ is linear.

Comment: @asdfd No, that's nowhere assumed that $f$ would be linear. If you have a question about some specific step, please point to it and I can elaborate.

Comment: Second implicaton: $f\left(\frac{(\cancel{w}-v)u+(v-\cancel{u})w}{w-u}\right) =\frac{f(v)((w-v)+(v-u))}{w-u}$

Comment: @asdfd There is no linearity being used or assumed there. It's just that by the definition of $\lambda$: $$f\big(\lambda u + (1-\lambda)w)\big) = f\left(\frac{(\cancel{w}-v)u+(v-\cancel{u})w}{w-u}\right) = f\left(\frac{v(w-u)}{w-u}\right) = f(v)$$ Then, in order to eliminate denominators, the inequality is multiplied by: $$w-u = (w-v)+(v-u)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline. If the function is not constant, there is some value $c \in [a, b]$ for which $f(c) \ne f(a)$. Since $f$ is increasing and $c > a$, $f(c) > f(a)$. By convexity the graph of $f$ is above the line through $(a, f(a))$ and $(c, f(c))$. Therefore on $[c, b]$, $f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: I understand the intuition behind this but I want to prove this formally.

Comment: @asdfd This is not a site for homework solutions, you need to provide your own input and tell us where your problems are.

Comment: This is not homework. This property for $f$ was assumed in a theorem proof. I'm trying to make the argument rigorous, since intuition can be deceptive.